# Задний фон обрезается в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css

При просмотре адаптивной версии сайта в браузере, проблем не возникает, но как только открываешь с мобильного устройства или планшета, задний фон обрезается. Что я делаю не так?

Html CSS код прилагаю по ссылке [ТЫК](https://codepen.io/MaKo51325/pen/poWmwBM)

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="main-bgFix">
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <a href="#" class="logo"><img class="logo1" src="img/new_logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
          <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li class="li-item">
              <a href="#portfolio" class="a-style">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li-item">
              <a href="#aboutMe" class="a-style">O mně</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li-item">
              <a href="#price" class="a-style">Ceník</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li-item">
              <a href="#kontakty" class="a-style">Kontakty</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="tel:+420770114540" class="a-style nav-hide">+0000</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="header-main">
          <h1 class="header-main__title">Dsdfkjsdfjsgdjgf</h1>
          <h2 class="header-main__title-2">Váš stylista a kadeřník v Brně</h2>
          <img src="img/scissors.svg" alt="" class="header-main__scissors" />
          <button class="header-main__button">
            <a href="https://n688921.yclients.com/" class="header-main__button-click">Online rezervace</a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>
```

```
.main-bgFix
background-image: url(../img/bg_main3.png)
background-position: center center
height: 100vh
max-width: 100%
```

Так же прикладываю скины как должно быть и как оно выглядить на самом деле
[image: 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По ссылке пример выглядит как попало и ничего проверить толком нельзя, но предположу что Вам нужно указать необходимый [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Не могли бы Вы выложить свой код прямо в тексте вопроса, а не через ссылки? Так будет понятнее и доступнее остальным участникам увидеть Ваш код и попытаться Вам помочь. (Для форматирования можете использовать Ctrl+M, для редактуры нажмите на кнопку [edit])

Answer (score 2):

Как сказал **@Simon** Вам надо использовать `background-size`, предположу что Вы хотите чтобы картинка не обрезалась, тогда Вам надо задать: `backround-size:100%`. Но это будет ужасным решением, ведь картинка будет растягиваться и сжиматься, лучше всего использовать `background-size: cover` тогда background будет выглядеть наиболее адекватно и типично для большинства проектов)

Документация на свойство [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)